# How to integrate tensorflow into QNX operating system

Tags: tensorflow, qnx

I want to use the tensorflow in a QNX operating system? The very first step is to integrate the tensorflow into QNX. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue on that on GitHub, unfortunately w/o a result but it's a starting point: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14753

Depending on your objective, NVIDIA's TensorRT can load TensorFlow models and provides binaries for QNX, see for example https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/pdf/TensorRT-Release-Notes.pdf